# LD_PRELOADING dlopen on android

Tags: android, c, gcc, android-ndk, ld-preload

I was curios about which libraries and Syscalls are used by my app while its running.So I started to investigate my app with LD_PRELOAD and some "syscalls" like open, access and write.

But while I'm trying to preload dlopen, to find out which libraries are loaded, I got this error: Symbol not found:

```
void* dlopen(const char *file, int mode){
    static void* (*o_dlopen) ( const char *file, int mode )=0;
    printf( "dlopen was called\n" );
    o_dlopen = (void*(*)(const char *file, int mode))   
    dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"dlopen");
    return (*o_dlopen)( file, mode );
}
```

It seems to be that dlsym is not able to find dlopen a second time. I compiled my preloaded *.so file with -ldl and the arm-gcc provided by android NDK. Using -rdynamic does not work either.

The preloading works fine but not for dlopen. Maybe you can help me...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling a `dlopen` function in your .so file by `dlopen`? You should follow the steps to do, `dlopen` -> `dlsym` -> `dlclose`

Comment: Not really. I created a dlopen in my *.so file to intercept the "real" dlopen. Then I use LD_Preload to wrap my so file around my app. My problem is that I'm not able to call the real dlopen via dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "dlopen"). I just got an error symbol not found.

Answer (score 0):

Android `dlopen` is offered *by the linker*, therefore you need to use `RTLD_DEFAULT` when looking up the `dlopen` symbol from your preloaded library. See: [bionic/libdl/libdl.c](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_bionic/blob/oreo-release/libdl/libdl.c) and [bionic/linker/linker.cpp](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_bionic/blob/oreo-release/linker/linker.cpp).